# AIC vs BIC for time series clustering and descriptive purposes

Tags: time-series, aic, gaussian-mixture-distribution, hidden-markov-model, bic

I'm in the process of fitting a hidden markov model with gaussian mixtures to time series health data. The primary purpose of this is **descriptive**, not predictive – I'm using the fitted model to give a broad description of the different 'clusters' within the data, and how the observed data points tended to move from one 'cluster' to another over time.

To choose the ideal 'model', my plan is to iterate through different numbers of states and Gaussian components, and calculate the AIC or BIC for each model. Then select the best model overall and use that for my descriptions.

I'm still on the fence over whether AIC or BIC is the best scoring criterion for my purposes. I'm not trying to identify the 'true' model, nor am I trying to optimise predictive ability. That being said, one of my later experiments will involve repeating the fitting process (for the final model parameters) using subsets of the data (e.g. 80-90% of the overall data), to show that the description provided is broadly consistent rather than overfitted to very specific data points / outliers.

My current feeling is AIC is probably the better criterion for model selection. Is this a reasonable conclusion? Is there another approach to model selection I haven't considered? I do have concerns about my small sample size (1200) given the number of free parameters as the model grows (e.g. 74 for a 5 state/5 component model) – I also considered AICc, but from my reading, this was published for use in linear regression models and the formula might not accurately apply in this case.

Comment: My understanding is that for most purposes, AIC is to prefer. So unless you have a very good reason to use BIC, use AIC.